# SetText of TextView in DialogFragment from Calling Activity

Tags: android, textview, android-dialogfragment, settext, findviewbyid

Building an Android app and having some trouble. I'd appreciate any help!

I have created an class that extends DialogFragment (Account_Create_Error) that I call from Activity A. I want to set the TextView field in this DialogFragment from Activity A. I created a method in my dialogfragment

```
public void setError(String message) {
           TextView error = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.message);
           error.setText(message);
}
```

I then use this method in Activity A by doing

```
Account_Create_Error error = new Account_Create_Error();
error.show(getFragmentManager(), "error");
error.setError(json.getString("response"));
```

I seem to get a nullpointer exception from findViewById.

Please let me know if providing any more of my code would be helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you calling `setContentView()` in your `Account_Create_Error` constructor?

Comment: Try using `view.findViewById(R.id.message)` in the `DialogFragment` `onViewCreated(...)` method and move your `TextView error;` declaration to be an instance member of the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: I am not calling setContentView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can pass data to dialog fragment using the constructor.

```
UserActionDialogFragment dialog = UserActionDialogFragment.newInstance(errorMesssage);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

Where `UserActionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment`

```
public class NotificationDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationDialogFragment";

    private String mMessageToDisplay;

    public static NotificationDialogFragment newInstance(
            String message) {

        NotificationDialogFragment infoDialog = new NotificationDialogFragment();
        mMessageToDisplay = message


    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialog.setMessage(mMessageToDisplay);
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.label_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });
        return alertDialog.create();
    }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. The only change I had to make was to use the view I had custom created to set the textview rather than setmessage. setmessage worked fine but I had a custom view so it just appeared at the top. Thank you again! You rock.

Comment: Welcome. Great to know that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get EditText from viewer thats set in builder, not getActivity(). This is should be enough

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);  
    EditText error = (EditText)(view.findViewById(R.id.message));
    ....
    return builder.create();
}
```

I didn't use onViewCreated method as mention above. The viewer is set up in builder as advised in [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend, i also have faced the same problem in one of my project.
I solve it in this way :
Create an interface and implement it in my fragment class. In my implemented function, i update my textView.
 (in your case, your need to initialize the errorTV before calling this function).

Comment: I'm trying this but failing to make it work. The app still crashes.

Should I be adding the interface to the DialogFragment and implementing it in the DialogFragment and in Activity A?

I tried implementing it in both, just in DialogFragment (not sure why this would work) and just in Activity A but nothing works.

Comment: My friend, you will implement this interface in FragmentActivity and call from Activity class like this (new FragmentClass().implementedFunction();)